# Friendly urls with htaccess in ads app

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm currently runing an classifieds ads site,
Php + Mysql (no frameworks)
Basically i have the ads listing page (ads.php) and the ads details page (ad_detail.php)

This is my current .htaccess:

```
# disable directory browsing
Options All -Indexes

ErrorDocument 400 /error.php
ErrorDocument 401 /error.php
ErrorDocument 403 /error.php
ErrorDocument 404 /error.php
ErrorDocument 500 /error.php
ErrorDocument 502 /error.php
ErrorDocument 504 /error.php

RewriteEngine on
```

This is the rewrite rule for the ads details:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)-da([0-9]+)$ ad_detail.php?ad=$2
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

The final result is something like this:

www.mysite.com/this-is-the-ad-detail-da50555 (the number is the ad id)

or
www.mysite.com/another-ad-detail-da50777

What i need is to get this:

**www.mysite.com/ads/another-ad-detail-da50777**

And

```
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

What can i do in others urls to show like www.mysite.com/about/ instead of www.mysite.com/about (without the /)

Answer (score 0):

You can have your rules like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule -da([0-9]+)/?$ ad_detail.php?ad=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```